# PHP, ajax, javascript, mysql: New Line/Carriage Return in a table not recognized

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm currently working on the following example found on http://www.webslesson.info/2017/07/live-add-edit-delete-datatables-records-using-php-ajax.html (entire code has been listed on this page) - everything works well for me apart from NewLine/Carriage return.

Whenever I press 'enter' key in the `First Name` or `Last Name` field, in order to add a new line, it basically won't recognize it.

In the source page file I added the code listed below after the: function fetch data() - please see the link: http://jsbin.com/yufovobinu/edit?html,output
but seems like it didn't help and carriage return/new line is still not recognized in Last Name field. I'm using Last Name field as a generic example, but it will happen to any text i would input to that field.
Additionally I'm including a video to visualise what happens when i type text in 'Last Name' field and then hit on 'enter' key and in order to insert data to mysql database (it sends data without new lines and returns it without new lines ): http://www.filedropper.com/issue

Please help! Thanks in advance!

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#user_data').keyup(function() {

$('#data2').html($(this).val().replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />'));
```

Comment: Show the HTML for the element `#text` and `#input`, they don't exist in the URL you pointed.

Comment: sorry about it, i tried this and i  included it in the source page file: $(document).ready(function() {

$('#user_data').keyup(function() {

$('#data2').html($(this).val().replace(/\r?\n/g, '<br />'));

Comment: I'm sorry, you'll have to paste more, it is really hard to understand what you are doing.Can you edit this: http://jsbin.com/wijowap/edit?html,output click File - save  and then paste the URL here?

Comment: I suggest to set `text` instead of `html`, so you haven't to replace new lines and is also more safe for XSS. Like this: `$('#data2').text($(this).val());`

Comment: @acdcjunior I edited and saved part of the code which i'm trying to add into the initial source page. Plus included a video to visualise what is my issue. I hope now it makes more sense, and sorry for not being specific, but i'm just a beginner :)

Comment: @GrowingBrick I tried with text instead of html as you suggested, but I might place this function in a wrong place because it's not working for me.

Comment: In your JSbin you are now using `text()` but still doing the `replace` of newline with `<br/>` tag. Can you try without it? I can't test on the empty table because the ajax request obviously fails

Comment: @GrowingBrick, i took <br/> tag off from the JSbin but now i can't type any longer in Last Name field, because all the characters are being immediately erased (video: http://www.filedropper.com/issue2)

Comment: Maybe this what I'm doing is only half way correct... what it has to do is to capture new lines typed in real time, submit to database with line breaks and retrieve from database with line breaks. the code i'm using in my source page comes from here: https://jsfiddle.net/fqnngd44/11/ but it might not be enough, or maybe i'm pasting it in a wrong place in that ajax script? would you recommend any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok now I understood what are you trying to do exactly. You don't need at all the `keyup` event, also you can send the data by ajax as it is, and store it in the database with the new line character unchanged in the text.

For displaying correctly the stored values when you print the table you have to output from PHP:

```
echo nl2br(htmlentities($row['columnName']));
```

Where htmlentities prevents other HTML tags from being executed (XSS vulnerability) and then replaces in a smart way all kind of new lines (`\r, \r\n, \n`) with a `<br>` tag using the PHP's native optimized function `nl2br`.

Comment: So this means i should forget about whole keyup thingy = delete it completely from ajax? and put: echo nl2br(htmlentities($row['last_name'])); in exactly same place? or in a different part of my source page? I also tried including it like this in the same place where i had keyup even: <?php  echo nl2br(htmlentities($row['last_name'])); ?> but no luck so far :( I'm pretty sure i'm doing something wrongly... sorry, if possible i will need some more details to complete it :(

Comment: No, I mean delete the keyup code from the JavaScript code and use nl2br and htmlentities when you fill the table by PHP. You haven't posted any PHP code. Reading AJAX calls it should be fetch.php. Is better that you post the code, I don't know how it output the data for that table, may be plain HTML, json encoded string or several other things

Comment: I deleted the keyup code from the JavaScript and next i went to past the echo you suggested above into fetch.php: http://jsbin.com/vanotemazo/edit?html I'm not sure if i'm going to the right place in this script to place the nl2br.

Comment: Yes that is the right place, but you need to remove the `echo` keyword because you are building a string, so it will be: `nl2br(htmlentities($row['last_name']))` also without the semicolon because the string continues...

Comment: I've gotten this error message when tried to open the source page while echo with nl2br has been already inserted into fetch.php : DataTables warning: table id=user_data - Ajax error. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/7

Comment: Please apply my last comment, as you written that JSbin it will throw 2 parse errors, so the json will be corrupted and your library won't be able to interpret it. However take a look at php.net manual, because it seems like you are missing important knowledge on syntax basics

Comment: I took 'echo' off the code: http://jsbin.com/zekapivufi/1/edit?html            but it seems that it didn't fix my problem, after pressing 'insert' button carriage returns will disappear and text will stick together in the same line with no space: http://www.filedropper.com/issue

Comment: Remember that you have applied it only on the last name column and not in the first one, however check by analyzing the element with the browser to view if a `<br>` is inside the cell, if so it is the library you are using the problem. Another check you can do is to directly read the database table to view if the new line char is present (use something like phpMyAdmin or MySQL Workbench)

Comment: I added it also for the first name column: nl2br(htmlentities($row['first_name'])) , however it remains with the same issue. I've inspected element and before clicking on 'insert' button there are <br> in the code, but once i click 'insert' they disappear, <br> are also not visible on when browsing records of this database in phpMyAdmin. My php documents have following settings: PHP in HTML, Unicode (UTF-8), Unix (LF)

Comment: In the database it is normal that you haven't the html tag `<br>` check only that the text has the new line and that is not all on the same line

Comment: There are no new lines in the database, it seem like text is still being added in the same line: https://imgur.com/a/7xMlT (screenshot from the database)

Comment: Change this: `var value = $(this).text();` before of  `update_data(id, column_name, value);` to this: `var value = $(this).html();`

Comment: Same thing for insert after: `$(document).on('click', '#insert', function(){` use `html()` to get values instead of `text()`

Comment: Issue persists, new lines disappear once i click 'insert' or sending a request to my database asking for a text update: 
current code on my source page: http://jsbin.com/cocidebago/edit?html,output
current code in fetch.php: http://jsbin.com/webefotuxu/edit?html

Comment: or could we somehow 'teach' our text area to recognize each 'enter' keypress as \n and before sending it to the database use the following: echo $data;

 $data = str_replace("\n", "<br/>", $data);

 echo "<br/><br/>" . $data;

Comment: Solved! replacing text with html did the trick, however i had some issues with CSS for my table and it was not working correctly at the beginning, but i made changes to my CSS bit and now everything works! thank you for your help @GrowingBrick